# Move combined fragment to top in StarUml

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, staruml

In star UML I am trying to make my combined fragment overlap the timelines but even though I click "Move to top" or "move to back" on the timeline, the combined fragment keeps being covered:

[image]

When I watch this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4wxr2Ztq9Y) the author doesnt seem to have this problem, as the combined fragment is on the top from the start.
I would appreciate all help really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in the current version 2.7 of StarUML. The [StarUML support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/staruml/NhnC4EMTUIo) has confirmed this limitation. They introduced a feature request to enable this in a future release.

So for the moment, the lifebar will always remain on top. You'll have to find a layout to avoid the overlaps.